# bulk image storage in sql server 2008

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008-r2

I am creating a asp.net app in C# .net 4.0 using VS 2008 & MS SQL Server 2008 R2. I want to upload image(.bmp) for each order and store it in DB corresponding to its order. It must be retrieved when View functionally is requested.

My requirement is to store images and retrieve it. Number of orders might be around 50 orders each day. It might be over be overhead as number increases. Please suggest me efficient method to overcome memory issue.

Comment: Compress the image? Buy a bigger hard disk? (What's your problem?)

Comment: There is no problem stated in your post. There is "Please suggest me efficient method to overcome memory issue" but no explanation what "memory issue" is. Both SQL and W2K8R2 x64 can handle pretty big files without much effort... Especially at your planned load of 2 request per hour.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can either store them in the database as varbinary(max) or store a URL to a file. If you have 50 images a day, it might be better to go for the file and URL method.

There's advantages and disadvantages to both. But as you said you want to store them in the DB:
I think one big one on the database storage is that no one can just come along and rename / delete the folder, or mess with the files in it.
Another good point for the database is that you can restore a database and not have to try to keep the keep the folder in sync.

You can use an ImageConverter to convert between an array of bytes to an image and back

```
     var stream = new MemoryStream();
     var imageData = DataAccess.GetImageData(); //Returns a System.Linq.Binary for me
     var imgageBinaryData = imageData.ImageData.ToArray(); //This returns a byte array
     var img =  Image.FromStream(stream);      //Here is your image ready for displaying
```

Then to go back something like

```
     var stream = new MemoryStream();
     img.Save(stream,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
     var myBytes = ms.ToArray();
```

Edit: Oh and storing them as Jpeg rather than Bmp will save a lotta space